# 6 element double precision vector matrix vector multiply in AVX

Tags: c++, c, optimization, avx

I need to do the following operation in double precision:

[image]

The numbers represent how the values are stored in memory. I want to implement this with AVX. Would it be best if I padded the columns of `[QK]` to 8 elements first, and then carried out a matrix vector multiplication with `[x]` and `[QK]` followed by a dot product?

EDIT: Ok, so I decided to implement a **FLOAT**  **32-bit** version with padded vectors as shown below:

```
// Perform matrix vector multiplication of QK*x            
// Load first four columns QK into 4 ymm registers    
ymm0 = _mm256_load_ps((float *)(QK));     
ymm1 = _mm256_load_ps((float *)(QK+8));       
ymm2 = _mm256_load_ps((float *)(QK+16));    
ymm3 = _mm256_load_ps((float *)(QK+24));  

// Load first four values of x
ymm4 = _mm256_broadcast_ss((float *)(x));
ymm5 = _mm256_broadcast_ss((float *)(x+1));
ymm6 = _mm256_broadcast_ss((float *)(x+2));
ymm7 = _mm256_broadcast_ss((float *)(x+3));

// Multiply in place - frees up ymm4,ymm5,ymm6,ymm7
ymm0 = _mm256_mul_ps(ymm0, ymm4);
ymm1 = _mm256_mul_ps(ymm1, ymm5);
ymm2 = _mm256_mul_ps(ymm2, ymm6);
ymm3 = _mm256_mul_ps(ymm3, ymm7);

// Add together, this frees up ymm1,ymm2,and ymm3
ymm0 = _mm256_add_ps(ymm0, ymm1);
ymm2 = _mm256_add_ps(ymm2, ymm3);
ymm0 = _mm256_add_ps(ymm0, ymm2);

// Load next last columns of QK
ymm1 = _mm256_load_ps((float *)(QK+32));     
ymm2 = _mm256_load_ps((float *)(QK+40)); 

// Load last two values of x
ymm6 = _mm256_broadcast_ss((float *)(x+4));
ymm7 = _mm256_broadcast_ss((float *)(x+5));

// Multiply in place
ymm1 = _mm256_mul_ps(ymm1, ymm6);
ymm2 = _mm256_mul_ps(ymm2, ymm7);

// Add together, this frees up every register except for ymm0
ymm0 = _mm256_add_ps(ymm0, ymm1);
ymm0 = _mm256_add_ps(ymm0, ymm2);  

// Answer stored in ymm0 and ymm1   
// Calculate dot product of y*(QK*x)
// Load x
ymm1 = _mm256_load_ps((float *)(y));   

// Do dotproduct by using horizontal multiply followed by horizontal add
// Multiply in place
ymm0 = _mm256_mul_ps(ymm0, ymm1);  

// Do horizontal sum
__m128 xmm1 = _mm256_extractf128_ps(ymm0, 1);
__m128 xmm2 = _mm256_extractf128_ps(ymm0, 0);
xmm2 = _mm_add_ps(xmm1, xmm2);
xmm1 = _mm_movehl_ps(xmm1, xmm2);
xmm2 = _mm_add_ps(xmm1, xmm2);
xmm1 = _mm_shuffle_ps(xmm2, xmm2, 1);
xmm2 = _mm_add_ss(xmm1, xmm2);
ans[0] = _mm_cvtss_f32(xmm2);
```

As it stands, it runs about 3 times faster than:

```
ans[0] = (QK[0]*x[0]+QK[8]*x[1]+QK[16]*x[2]+QK[24]*x[3]+QK[32]*x[4]+QK[40]*x[5])*y[0]+
         (QK[1]*x[0]+QK[9]*x[1]+QK[17]*x[2]+QK[25]*x[3]+QK[33]*x[4]+QK[41]*x[5])*y[1]+
         (QK[2]*x[0]+QK[10]*x[1]+QK[18]*x[2]+QK[26]*x[3]+QK[34]*x[4]+QK[42]*x[5])*y[2]+
         (QK[3]*x[0]+QK[11]*x[1]+QK[19]*x[2]+QK[27]*x[3]+QK[35]*x[4]+QK[43]*x[5])*y[3]+
         (QK[4]*x[0]+QK[12]*x[1]+QK[20]*x[2]+QK[28]*x[3]+QK[36]*x[4]+QK[44]*x[5])*y[4]+
         (QK[5]*x[0]+QK[13]*x[1]+QK[21]*x[2]+QK[29]*x[3]+QK[37]*x[4]+QK[45]*x[5])*y[5];
```

For 500mil iterations, the standard C version runs at about 9 seconds, and the single precision AVX version runs at about 3.5 seconds. If I comment out the horizonal sum at the end then it runs in about 0.5 seconds. The horizontal sum really kills the performance...

Comment: For windows 7, you can use 8 of the ymm registers ---> 6 for matrix elements 1 for vector a 1 for vector b. For linux it is 16 ymm registers free.

Comment: Oops, I should have specified, these are double precision. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik you get 8 ymm registers on x86, 16 registers on x64.

Comment: Unless someone takes the time to implement and profile this themselves, it will be difficult to definitively answer your question. Have you considered loading the first 4 elements of the rows of QK and the first 4 elements of y in an AVX register, and the last two elements into SSE registers? That might save you the trouble of padding and I don't see any downside. Don't forget the first 128 bits of AVX registers are aliased to the SSE registers!

Comment: @dsharlet I was just looking for general pointers and tips I guess. Also, I wanted to avoid using SSE with AVX because there's a penality when switching between them. Is there an AVX instruction for only loading the lower half of the YMM register? `[x]` and `[y]` will both be 32 byte aligned.

Comment: If you have fma4 then that could be even quicker.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik I only have access to sandybridge. To my knowledge the FMA instructions are only available on haswell?

Comment: @jucestain You can still use AVX instructions on SSE registers to avoid the transition penalty. See this document: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/avoiding-avx-sse-transition-penalties

Comment: @dsharlet do you know what instrinsic I should use? Would I use an SSE instrinsic to load the 2 doubles, and then use an AVX instruction on the SSE register?

Comment: Yes, maybe on haswell.

Comment: @dsharlet So I've looked around a bit. Do you think I should load the two lower doubles with `_mm_load_pd` into an xmm register, and then use `_mm256_castpd128_pd256` to "convert it to a ymm register before calling any of the AVX arithmetic operations. I feel like calling this function shouldn't even incur any overhead since it's not really doing anything, seeing as how the ymm is another alias for xmm with just the first two doubles undefined.

Comment: @jucestain I think you have a good question about how to use the AVX instructions on SSE registers with intrinsics. I'm not sure. I think the approach you identified will result in the transition penalty, unless you can convince your compiler to emit AVX instructions for SSE operations (apparently this can be done in the Intel compiler per the document I linked earlier).

Comment: @jucestain I was also thinking about this more, you might be better off simply using SSE for the whole operation. Every other row of your matrix will not be aligned correctly for AVX loads, and the instruction latency for vdpps is one add longer than dpps anyways, so I'm not sure you are gaining enough to justify the unaligned load. You'll have to try the various approaches and profile them to answer your question definitively. edit: forgot you are looking at doubles, but I would assume the same latency issue applies there.

Comment: @dsharlet Yea, you may be right with the SSE. I'll try to do this with AVX (using the cast), SSE, and then AVX with padding and see which works best.

Comment: I think this is a misunderstanding of the performance penalty of mixing AVX and SSE. This penalty is incurred only if the compiled code mixes legacy SSE instructions and the new VEX-encoded instructions. This is taken care of by the compiler, i.e., the compiler will encode all instructions using the VEX coding scheme if you select AVX as your architecture. You should worry about it only when you are calling old precompiled libraries with legacy SSE instructions. So go ahead and use both 128-bit and 256-bit intrinsics. (http://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_assembly.pdf, Sec 13.6)

Comment: @NorbertP. That clears some things up. Thanks!

Comment: To compare results, I did [x][QK][y] on 5000000 single precision x,y vectors (5000000*6*4*2 = 229MB of floats) 100 times.  That should be equivalent to your 500mil iterations you quote.  On my i5-3317U CPU @ 1.70GHz the scalar (standard) code takes 14.8s.  That's in the same ball park as your number of 9s  (I'm using only an ultra book at the conference I'm stuck at).  However, the AVX code on this system takes only 2.2s.  That's about a 6.6 speedup.  For a smaller number of vectors I get closer to 8x, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created code to do this efficiently. I get nearly a 4x speed up (best you can expect with doubles on AVX) using AVX for a single thread.  Here are the results running over 2000, 32000, and 4000000 x and y six-component vectors over a 6x6 matrix.  These roughly correspond to L2, L3, and >>L3 cache size on my system (each vector uses 48 bytes).

Edit: I added text (and code) at the end to do this with float.  The speedup is nearly 8x with AVX on a single thread.

```
i5-3317U (2 core ivy bridge)
compiled with: g++ m6.cpp -o m6 -O3 -mavx -fopenmp 
nvec 2000, repeat 10000, 1 thread : time scalar/SIMD 3.95
nvec 32000, repeat 1000, 1 thread : time scalar/SIMD 3.53
nvec 4000000, repeat 10, 1 thread : time scalar/SIMD 3.28
1 thread for both the SIMD and non-SIMD functions 

nvec 2000, repeat 10000, 2 threads: time scalar/SIMD 5.96
nvec 32000, repeat 1000, 2 threads: time scalar/SIMD 5.88
nvec 4000000, repeat 10, 2 threads: time scalar/SIMD 4.52
2 threads on the SIMD function vs. 1 thread on the non-SIMD function

compiled with g++ m6.cpp -o m6 -O3 -msse4.2 -fopenmp
nvec 2000, repeat 10000, 1 thread: time scalar/SIMD 2.15
nvec 32000, repeat 1000, 1 thread: time scalar/SIMD 2.06 
nvec 4000000, repeat 10, 1 thread: time scalar/SIMD 2.00
```

The basic algorithm does SIMD on the x and y vectors, NOT on the 6x6 matrix.  One key point is that the x and y vectors have to be arrays of blocks of struct of arrays.  This is also called an array of struct of arrays (AoSoA) or hybrid struct of arrays.  You can read more about it here "Extending a C-like Language for Portable SIMD Programming"
http://www.sci.utah.edu/~wald/Publications/2012///ppopp/download//vecimp.pdf

Below is the code.  The function `aos2aosoa` converts arrays of six component vectors to arrays of SoA.  Your application should generate the vectors in this form (not do the conversion) if you want to get the full benefit of SIMD.  This code uses Agner Fog's vectorclass http://www.agner.org/optimize/#vectorclass .  It's just some header files.  This code will also work with SSE (but the boost is only about 2x as expected).

One small caveat, the arrays of x and y vectors and results have to be multiples of 4.  However, the number of vectors does not.

Compile like this

```
g++ m6.cpp -o m6 -O3 -mavx -fopenmp  //system with AVX
g++ m6.cpp -o m6 -O3 -msse4.2 -fopenmp //system with SSE
```

In visual studio put /arch:AVX in the compiler commmand line options

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include "vectorclass.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

double prod_scalar(double *x, double *M, double *y) {
    double sum = 0.0f;
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<6; j++) {
            sum += x[i]*M[i*6 + j]*y[j];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

void prod_block4(double *x, double *M, double *y, double *result) {
    Vec4d sum4 = 0.0f;
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {
        Vec4d x4 = Vec4d().load(&x[4*i]);
        for(int j=0; j<6; j++) {
            Vec4d y4 = Vec4d().load(&y[4*j]);
            sum4 += x4*M[i*6 + j]*y4;
        }
    }
    sum4.store(result);
}

void prod_block4_unroll2(double *x, double *M, double *y, double *result) {
    Vec4d sum4_1 = 0.0f;
    Vec4d sum4_2 = 0.0f;
    Vec4d yrow[6];
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {
        yrow[i] = Vec4d().load(&y[4*i]);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {
        Vec4d x4 = Vec4d().load(&x[4*i]);
        for(int j=0; j<6; j+=2) {
            sum4_1 += x4*M[i*6 + j]*yrow[j];
            sum4_2 += x4*M[i*6 + j+1]*yrow[j+1];
        }
    }
    sum4_1 += sum4_2;
    sum4_1.store(result);
}
void loop_scalar(double *x, double *M, double *y, double *result, const int nvec) {
//  #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i=0; i<nvec; i++) {
        result[i] = prod_scalar(&x[6*i], M, &y[6*i]);
    }   
}

void loop_block4(double *x, double *M, double *y, double *result, const int nvec) {
//  #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i=0; i<(nvec/4); i++) {
//      prod_block4(&x[i*24], M, &y[i*24], &result[4*i]);
        prod_block4_unroll2(&x[i*24], M, &y[i*24], &result[4*i]);
    }
}


void aos2soa(double *in, double *out) {
    int cnt = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<4; j++) {
            out[cnt++] = in[6*j + i];
        }
    }
}

void aos2aosoa(double *in, double *out, const int nvec) {
    for(int i=0; i<(nvec/4); i++) {
        aos2soa(&in[i*24], &out[i*24]);
    }
}

double compare_results(double *r1, double * r2, const int nvec) {
    double out = 0.0f;
    for(int i=0; i<nvec; i++) {
        out += r1[i] -r2[i];
        //if(out!=0) printf("%f %f\n",r1[i], r2[i]);
    }
    return out;
}

void loop(const int nvec, const int repeat) {
    double *M = (double*)_mm_malloc(6*6*sizeof(double),32);
    double *x_aos = (double*)_mm_malloc(nvec*6*sizeof(double),32);
    double *y_aos = (double*)_mm_malloc(nvec*6*sizeof(double),32);
    double *x_aosoa = (double*)_mm_malloc(nvec*6*sizeof(double),32);
    double *y_aosoa = (double*)_mm_malloc(nvec*6*sizeof(double),32);
    double *results_scalar = (double*)_mm_malloc(nvec*sizeof(double),32);
    double *results_vector = (double*)_mm_malloc(nvec*sizeof(double),32);

    for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<6; j++) {
            M[j*6 + i] = i*6 + j; 
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<(6*nvec); i++) {
        double r1 = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX;
        double r2 = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX;
        //x_aos[i] = i;
        x_aos[i] = r1;
        //y_aos[i] = i;
        y_aos[i] = r2;

    } 

    aos2aosoa(x_aos, x_aosoa, nvec);
    aos2aosoa(y_aos, y_aosoa, nvec);

    double dtime;
    dtime = omp_get_wtime();
    for(int i=0; i<repeat; i++) {
        loop_scalar(x_aos, M, y_aos, results_scalar, nvec);
    }
    dtime = omp_get_wtime() - dtime;
    printf("time scalar %f\n", dtime);

    double dtime_old = dtime;
    dtime = omp_get_wtime();
    for(int i=0; i<repeat; i++) {
        loop_block4(x_aosoa, M, y_aosoa, results_vector, nvec);
    }
    dtime = omp_get_wtime() - dtime;
    printf("time vector %f\n", dtime);
    printf("time scalar/vector %f\n", dtime_old/dtime);

    printf("difference %f\n", compare_results(results_scalar, results_vector, nvec));

    _mm_free(M);
    _mm_free(x_aos);
    _mm_free(y_aos);
    _mm_free(x_aosoa);
    _mm_free(y_aosoa);
    _mm_free(results_scalar);
    _mm_free(results_vector);

}

int main() {
    int nveca[3];
    nveca[0] = 2000; // 2000*2*6*8 = 192kb //L2
    nveca[1] = 32000; // 32000*2*6*8 = 3Mb //L3
    nveca[2] = 4*1000000; //366Mb
    int nrepeat[3];
    nrepeat[0] = 10000;
    nrepeat[1] = 1000;
    nrepeat[2] = 10;
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        printf("nvec %d, repeat %d\n", nveca[i], nrepeat[i]);
        loop(nveca[i], nrepeat[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Here are the results for float.  The boost is about 8x

```
nvec 2000, repeat 10000, 1 thread:  time scalar/SIMD 7.86
nvec 32000, repeat 1000, 1 thread:  time scalar/SIMD 7.63
nvec 5000000, repeat 100, 1 thread: time scalar/SIMD 6.63
```

Here is the code for float instead of double

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include "vectorclass.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ROUND_DOWN(x, s) ((x) & ~((s)-1))

float prod_scalar(float *x, float *M, float *y) {
    float sum = 0.0f;
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<6; j++) {
            sum += x[i]*M[i*6 + j]*y[j];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

float prod_scalar_unroll2(float *x, float *M, float *y) {
    float sum_1 = 0.0f;
    float sum_2 = 0.0f;
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<6; j+=2) {
            sum_1 += x[i]*M[i*6 + j]*y[j];
            sum_2 += x[i]*M[i*6 + j+1]*y[j+1];
        }
    }
    return sum_1 + sum_2;
}

void prod_block4(float *x, float *M, float *y, float *result) {
    Vec8f sum4 = 0.0f;
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {
        Vec8f x4 = Vec8f().load(&x[8*i]);
        for(int j=0; j<6; j++) {
            Vec8f y4 = Vec8f().load(&y[8*j]);
            sum4 += x4*M[i*6 + j]*y4;
        }
    }
    sum4.store(result);
}

void prod_block4_unroll2(float *x, float *M, float *y, float *result) {
    Vec8f sum4_1 = 0.0f;
    Vec8f sum4_2 = 0.0f;
    Vec8f yrow[6];
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {
        yrow[i] = Vec8f().load(&y[8*i]);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {
        Vec8f x4 = Vec8f().load(&x[8*i]);
        for(int j=0; j<6; j+=2) {
            sum4_1 += x4*M[i*6 + j]*yrow[j];
            sum4_2 += x4*M[i*6 + j+1]*yrow[j+1];
        }
    }
    sum4_1 += sum4_2;
    sum4_1.store(result);
}

void loop_scalar(float *x, float *M, float *y, float *result, const int nvec) {
//  #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i=0; i<nvec; i++) {
        result[i] = prod_scalar(&x[6*i], M, &y[6*i]);
        //result[i] = prod_scalar_unroll2(&x[6*i], M, &y[6*i]);
    }   
}

void loop_SIMD(float *x, float *M, float *y, float *result, const int nvec) {
    //#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static,256)
    //#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
    const int N = nvec/8;
    //printf("chuck %d\n", N/2);
    //omp_set_num_threads(2);

    //#pragma omp parallel 
    {
        //int nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
        //int ithread = omp_get_thread_num();

        //int start = (ithread*N)/nthreads;
        //int end = ((ithread+1)*N)/nthreads;
        //printf("ithread, start %d, end %d, chunk %d\n",start, end, end-start);
        //#pragma omp for 
        for(int i=0; i<(nvec/8); i++) {
        //for(int i=start; i<end; i++) {
    //      prod_block4(&x[i*24], M, &y[i*24], &result[4*i]);
        prod_block4_unroll2(&x[i*48], M, &y[i*48], &result[8*i]);
        }
    }
}

void aos2soa(float *in, float *out) {
    int cnt = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<8; j++) {
            out[cnt++] = in[6*j + i];
        }
    }
}

void aos2aosoa(float *in, float *out, const int nvec) {
    for(int i=0; i<(nvec/8); i++) {
        aos2soa(&in[i*48], &out[i*48]);
    }
}

float compare_results(float *r1, float * r2, const int nvec) {
    float out = 0.0f;
    for(int i=0; i<nvec; i++) {
        out += r1[i] -r2[i];
        //if(out!=0) printf("%f %f\n",r1[i], r2[i]);
    }
    return out;
}

void loop(const int nvec, const int repeat) {
    float *M = (float*)_mm_malloc(6*6*sizeof(float),64);
    float *x_aos = (float*)_mm_malloc(nvec*6*sizeof(float),64);
    float *y_aos = (float*)_mm_malloc(nvec*6*sizeof(float),64);
    float *x_aosoa = (float*)_mm_malloc(nvec*6*sizeof(float),64);
    float *y_aosoa = (float*)_mm_malloc(nvec*6*sizeof(float),64);
    float *results_scalar = (float*)_mm_malloc(nvec*sizeof(float),64);
    float *results_SIMD = (float*)_mm_malloc(nvec*sizeof(float),64);

    for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<6; j++) {
            M[j*6 + i] = i*6 + j; 
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<(6*nvec); i++) {
        float r1 = (float)rand()/RAND_MAX;
        float r2 = (float)rand()/RAND_MAX;
        //x_aos[i] = i;
        x_aos[i] = r1;
        //y_aos[i] = i;
        y_aos[i] = r2;

    } 

    aos2aosoa(x_aos, x_aosoa, nvec);
    aos2aosoa(y_aos, y_aosoa, nvec);

    float dtime;
    dtime = omp_get_wtime();
    for(int i=0; i<repeat; i++) {
        loop_scalar(x_aos, M, y_aos, results_scalar, nvec);
    }
    dtime = omp_get_wtime() - dtime;
    printf("time scalar %f\n", dtime);

    float dtime_old = dtime;
    dtime = omp_get_wtime();
    for(int i=0; i<repeat; i++) {
        loop_SIMD(x_aosoa, M, y_aosoa, results_SIMD, nvec);
    }
    dtime = omp_get_wtime() - dtime;
    printf("time SIMD %f\n", dtime);
    printf("time scalar/SIMD %f\n", dtime_old/dtime);

    printf("difference %f\n", compare_results(results_scalar, results_SIMD, nvec));

    _mm_free(M);
    _mm_free(x_aos);
    _mm_free(y_aos);
    _mm_free(x_aosoa);
    _mm_free(y_aosoa);
    _mm_free(results_scalar);
    _mm_free(results_SIMD);

}

int main() {
    int nveca[3];
    nveca[0] = 2000; // 2000*2*6*8 = 192kb //L2
    nveca[1] = 32000; // 32000*2*6*8 = 3Mb //L3
    nveca[2] = 5*1000000; //366Mb
    int nrepeat[3];
    nrepeat[0] = 10000;
    nrepeat[1] = 1000;
    nrepeat[2] = 100;
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        printf("nvec %d, repeat %d\n", nveca[i], nrepeat[i]);
        loop(nveca[i], nrepeat[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach. But there are still problems like you mentioned (only needing the diagonal components of the resulting matrix). Also think there will still be the problem of alignment when loading the 6x6 QK matrix... I'll look into it further. I'll post what I append what I did yesterday to the question later tonight

Comment: I know to to get only the diagonal components now.  I'll try and post the solution soon or tomorrow.

Comment: Okay, I edited my answer to show the basic algorithm.  I can try and post some example code and clean up the part about how to arrange the memory (in case it's not clear) over the next few days.

Comment: Sounds good. I'll be checking on this throughout the next few days.

Comment: I updated (changed my answer).  I get about a 4x (depending on the number of vectors) speedup with AVX on doubles compared to non SIMD code.  I think that's about as much as one can expect.  I verified that the SIMD function gets the same result as the non SIMD function.

Comment: I need time to go through this to digest/understand it. I will get back to you in a few days or so. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: So if I understand your code correctly, instead of doing the `[x]*[QK]*[y]` operation itself in parallel, you are essentially doing four (for doubles) of them in parallel? Is this correct? I think this is definitely the way to go. Much more efficient and you don't need to worry about the horizontal sum at the end which I tried to implement. Also, thanks for the article, I'll try to read it in more depth tonight.

Comment: Yes, I think that's the way to think of it.  A lot of people do SIMD wrong and make it harder than it needs to be.  The irony is that the correct way to use SIMD has almost the same syntax as the scalar code (compare prod_scalar and prod_block4).  I always write the scalar code first to see how to do the SIMD.  Switching topics slightly, I got SIMD working efficiently but with the threading could be more efficiently.  On two cores with double I expect 8x (4x from SIMD and 2x from the cores) but if you look at my results I only get 6x.  I don't know why yet.

Comment: A small update to the threading.  I parallelized the loop that repeats the function rather than the function itself and I get close to 7x (out of max 8x) so I think that says the OpenMP overhead is causing the threading inefficiency in this case.